# How can I count the number of groups/field values for an ID?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of detail for which **I want to count user_ids that had 2 or more different values of action_taken.**

**Detail:**

```
| user_id | action_taken          | action_date |
|---------|-----------------------|-------------|
| 1234    | clicked on a link     | 1/1/2017    |
| 1234    | went to the home page | 1/5/2017    |
| 1234    | clicked on a link     | 1/7/2017    |
| 1234    | clicked on a link     | 1/9/2017    |
| 1234    | changed password      | 1/11/2017   |
| 1234    | clicked on a link     | 1/13/2017   |
| 9876    | went to the home page | 2/1/2017    |
| 9876    | went to the home page | 2/5/2017    |
| 9876    | went to the home page | 2/7/2017    |
| 9876    | went to the home page | 2/9/2017    |
| 5566    | clicked on a link     | 1/1/2017    |
| 5566    | clicked on a link     | 1/5/2017    |
| 5566    | changed password      | 1/7/2017    |
| 5566    | clicked on a link     | 1/9/2017    |
| 4433    | went to the home page | 1/5/2017    |
```

**Desired output:**

Output 1: Return the number of different values of actions_taken.

```
| user_id | number_dift_action_taken_values |
|---------|---------------------------------|
| 1234    | 3                               |
| 4433    | 1                               |
| 5566    | 2                               |
| 9876    | 1                               |
```

Output 2: Return only the user_ids that had >=2 different values of action_taken.

```
| user_id |
|---------|
| 1234    |
| 5566    |
```

Here's what I have so far that isn't working: http://rextester.com/TUL87833. The HAVING clause is counting number of rows *in the detail* that belong to each group, **not**
the number of number of groups specified by the GROUP BY user_id, action_taken clause...

```
select
    user_id
    ,action_taken
    ,count(*)
from
    tbl
group by
    user_id
    ,action_taken
having count(*) >=2;

| user_id | action_taken          | count |
|---------|-----------------------|-------|
| 1234    | clicked on a link     | 4     |
| 5566    | clicked on a link     | 3     |
| 9876    | went to the home page | 4     |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output 1

```
SELECT user_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT action_taken) number_dift_action_taken_values
  FROM t_tab
 GROUP BY user_id
```

Result

```
user_id number_dift_action_taken_values
1234    3
4433    1
5566    2
9876    1
```

Output 2

```
SELECT user_id
  FROM t_tab
 GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT action_taken) >= 2
```

Result

```
user_id
1234
5566
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with something like the following for each output #:

Output 1:

```
select 
user_id
,count(distinct action_taken) as number_dift_action_taken_values
into #Output1_tbl
from details_tbl 
group by user_id
```

Output 2:

```
select *
from #Output1_tbl
where number_dift_action_taken_values >= 2
```